# moving buttons in C# windows 8 immersive application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I need to write a windows 8 immersive application (windows store app) in C# that requires me to insert buttons programatically into a Grid at Random.

My Xaml creates a grid like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I then want to be able to create a button in the code behind:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Content = label;
```

and then insert it into the grid, but I haven't figured out how this can be done. (I want to add an arbitrary number of buttons to the grid, well smaller than the number of cells)

I've looked through the grid definitions and it has a RowDefinitions and CollumnDefinitions, but neither of these appear to give you the ability to add things into the cells.

Anybody have any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Is this a windows store app or a windows desktop application?

Comment: I'm talking about a windows store app. Thanks, I've edited the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `Button` to the `Grid`'s children collection. From there you can then set the row, column of the button using some static methods:

```
// instance method on grid (lower case g)
grid.Children.Add(button1);
// static methods on Grid (upper case G)
Grid.SetRow(button1, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(button1, 0);
```